# code generation / syntax representation of Go type

Tags: go, syntax

In Go std lib there're some way to pretty printing object into a Go-Syntax representation, for example,here'd how to pretty print a value,

https://play.golang.org/p/hztlPEf1If

so is there any way to dump definition of a *type*? If no, what's the challenges behind to stop having this feature.

Comment: Do you mean like dumping a Struct and get all fields with name and also the type of field? It can be done using the reflection.

Comment: @Apin should be yes. forgot to mention, my scenarios is trying to code generate based on existing type, most of the time, struct. not sure if any handy way of doing this, I feel using reflect is possible but also significant detail to handle. So I'm wondering if I missed any existing facility.

Comment: Better also to mention on your question, what kind input and also the output you want.

Comment: here's the example output. It's used to be part of a code generation tool.
https://play.golang.org/p/LEJHEsmxQ3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write little reflection function that maybe it help you. Please check :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type S struct {
    A string
    B int
    c bool
    d float64
    e struct {
          f int
      }
}

func main() {
    var s S
    MagicPrint(&s)
}

func MagicPrint(t interface{}) {
    typeOfT := reflect.TypeOf(t).Elem()
    fmt.Println("type", typeOfT.Name(), " struct {")

    for i := 0; i < typeOfT.NumField(); i++ {
        f := typeOfT.Field(i)
        fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", f.Name, f.Type)
    }
    fmt.Println("}")
}
```

Check in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bSnpJvMDux)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I think I'd go to roll own solution (based on ^) as can't found any existing lib doing this job in a more complete way.